# Get ActionID for Spotify events under windows

Tags: python, windows, spotify

I know my title is a little unclear but let me explain.

I am thinking of making an application which will notify the current playing song's name and artist via notification icon in windows.

I looked at `toastify` but for some reason it is not working on my system.

I am currently using [pytify](http://code.google.com/p/pytify/) to fetch the current playing track's artist and name.

The problem I am facing is how to detect the `next song change` event for spotify in windows.

I looked at `pytify's` source code and found that it is using certain `Command ID's` like

```
# Command IDs
CMD_PLAYPAUSE   = 917504
CMD_STOP        = 851968
CMD_PREVIOUS    = 786432
CMD_NEXT        = 720896
```

to control spotify.

First of all what **application** one has to use to get these ID.

and how to get the same ID for `next song change` event or I am handling the problem in the wrong way.

PS: Linux users are familiar with *dbus software* to handle similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like spotify itself doesn't have a "callback" api, so you'll have to do this manually by hooking into SendMessage events. I am not sure if you can do this with pyhook using a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook. You can then watch for title changes in your windows (which I think uses the WM_SETTEXT event)

Comment: If I understand you correctly what you mean is my python script/program should wait till `spotifymainwindow` fires the `WM_SETTEXT` event and than capture the event and do what stuff it has to do. Can you suggest me some reading in relation to this stuff(pywin32,events,messages).

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if you can do this in pyhook, though. You may need to use pywin32. See this thread: http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/window-events-via-SetWindowsHookExA-td1956530.html

Comment: Please see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634124/setting-up-hook-on-wm-settext-message-through-python. Thanks for the help.